# Using bash commands in keyboard shortcuts

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, notification, sh

I'm trying to set a keyboard shortcut for `notify-send $(fortune)` but when I activate it, it just sends a notification that says `$(fortune)` instead of actually giving a fortune. Note that if I run it in the terminal, it works as intended (i.e. sends a notification with the result of `fortune`). This seems to imply that when the keyboard shortcut is activated, it isn't interpreting it as a bash command, but rather as simply running the program `notify-send` with argument `$(fortune)`.

How do I get it to interpret it correctly?

Note that I've tried putting it in a shell script and doing `sh ~/tell-fortune.sh`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

`$(...)` is a shell feature, and the keyboard shortcut command is not run in a shell.

Try this instead:

```
sh -c 'notify-send $(fortune)'
```

As for `sh tell-fortune.sh`, without giving the full path to `tell-fortune.sh`, where would `sh` look for it?

As for `sh ~/tell-fortune.sh`, `~` is *also* a shell feature, without a shell, it will look for a file at the relative path `~/tell-fortune.sh`, where `~` is taken as-is.

Comment: So just use the absolute path?